# Converting text to hyperlinks on the fly or store them in a DB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a comments section on a webpage (similar to like on SO) where people can leave text but also links. It works using a standard textfield which does not allow HTML to be included. There is no formatting options etc.

Because no HTML is allowed, I need to parse links (basically text that begins with http or www) and then wrap it in an `<a>` tag.

To do this on the server would mean using something like JSoup to parse the text and then do the wrapping before inserting it with the rest of the comment text into my DB.

Alternatively, I was thikning that JQuery could scan ALL the comments on the page and wrap anything beginning with a http or www with the `<a>` tag.

Which one is the correct/better/more efficient method? I have a hunch that the JQuery way will cause some page slowdowns because its updating the DOM constantly on the fly but would like some confirmation from an expert!

Comment: I would suggest to save the text as it is and when someone request it then return as link  you will  have more control how you want to use it. You can already have page with a tags and simply set the href or you can return as list of tags what ever you want

Comment: @Raider there could be 1000s of comments on the page... is it still feasible to do it on the fly?

Comment: You would not return all link at once so I think there should not be any problem

Answer (score 2):

When you consider you might at some point want to parse markdown or replace emoticons with images etc., thinking about the performance impact is a good decision.

Usually, you have 3 options:

#### 1. Transform hyperlinks in the backend

I'll assume PHP here, but the principle stays the same:

```
function renderComment($comment) {
  $commentHtml = transformLinks($comment->comment_text);
  // render $commentHtml
}
```

This has the disadvantage of having to replace texts for *every* comment, on *every* page request, and is therefore not recommended. On the plus side, compared to option 2, you only have to store the comment text once.

#### 2. Transform hyperlinks in the backend and store them in the database

Assuming PHP and MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (id ..., comment_text TEXT, comment_html TEXT, ...)
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
function saveComment($createdOrChangedComment) {
  $comment->comment_html = transformLinks($comment->comment_text);
  saveToDatabase($comment);
}

function renderComment($comment) {
  $commentHtml = $comment->comment_html;
  // render $commentHtml
}
```

This means you have to store the comment text twice in the database, once as text, once as html - assuming you want some sort of "edit" button; if not, only saving the html is fine.
While taking up a bit more database space, this solution only fetches the pre-rendered HTML from the database and is therefore better performance-wise.

#### 3. Transforming hyperlinks in the front-end

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.comment').each(function(commentElement) {
    // Do magic
    transformCommentToHTML(commentElement);
  });
});
```

This should be fine performance-wise when you only have a few hundred comments.
If there are thousands of comments loaded to the DOM at once (which might be a performance hit in itself, but let's ignore that for now), the parsing might be noticable since it happens synchronously and blocks the browser.
In such a case you can parse/replace one pack of comments at a time (e.g. 300) and return the control back to the browser between parsing.

#### 3.b Transform hyperlinks in the frontend, batch-by-batch

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var $comments = jQuery('.comment');
  var currentComment = 0;
  (function transformCommentBatch() {
    for (var batchLimit = currentComment + 300; currentComment < $comments.length && currentComment < batchLimit; currentComment++) {
      // Do magic
      transformCommentToHTML($comments[currentComment]);
    }
    if (currentComment < $comments.length) {
      // Don't freeze the browser, continue in the next frame
      setTimeout(transformCommentBatch, 1);
    }
  }());
});
```

That way, the browser can handle events and does not appear "frozen" to the user, while your first 300 comments in the DOM are transformed first - these are most likely on top of the page and the only ones visible on page load.